# What all can be used between two "%" signs in windows file explorer to quickly navigate to a specific location?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

If this should be asked in another site, please let me know. I apologize as I do not know the correct nomenclature for what this is called.

Example: Using %localappdata% will navigate me to "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local". Is there a list of all these possible shortcuts that I can use between two "%" signs?

Also, what would the correct name for these be called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `%sometext%` syntax is a Windows mechanism that applies to both Explorer and the Command prompt.
It is called "Environment variable expansion".
The sequence is simply replaced (aka "expanded") by the text stored in the environment variable called "sometext".

So `%localappdata%` is simply replaced by whatever is stored in the environment variable called 'localappdata' which happens to be `c:\users\user\appdata\local` in your case.

To see a list of all available environment variables open a Command Prompt window and give the command `SET`.
(Or in PowerShell give the command `dir env:`.)
That will show all variables and their current value.
Obviously only those that contain a path (not all do) make sense to be used in Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Supplemental to Tonny's answer:

using the format:

- **`explorer "shell:<KnownFolderName>"`**

You can access additional locations, including virtual folders, such as **`This PC`**, using:

- **`explorer "shell:MyComputerFolder"`**

The KnownFolders are defined in the registry under:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions
```

You can generate a list of the names in **PowerShell** using:

```
( 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions' | gci | gp ).Name
```

Most (but not all) of the names work in this manner:

```
AccountPictures
Roaming Tiles
Common Programs
PublicAccountPictures
GameTasks
UserProfiles
MyComputerFolder
SearchHistoryFolder
Local Pictures
SyncSetupFolder
DpapiKeys
Retail Demo
Favorites
My Video
SearchHomeFolder
RecordedTVLibrary
System
Libraries
ThisDeviceFolder
AppsFolder
MusicLibrary
CommonVideo
OneDriveDocuments
SyncResultsFolder
LocalizedResourcesDir
Cookies
CameraRollLibrary
Original Images
Recorded Calls
3D Objects
CommonMusic
OneDrivePictures
My Pictures
Cache
Local Videos
Downloads
SavedPictures
CommonDownloads
AppData
SyncCenterFolder
PublicLibraries
VideosLibrary
My Music
ConflictFolder
SavedGames
InternetFolder
HomeGroupFolder
Quick Launch
SystemCertificates
AppDataProgramData
Contacts
UserProgramFiles
Device Metadata Store
Profile
Start Menu
Common AppData
ProgramFilesCommonX64
PhotoAlbums
ProgramFilesX64
ConnectionsFolder
Administrative Tools
ThisPCDesktopFolder
OneDriveCameraRoll
PrintersFolder
AppMods
DocumentsLibrary
AppDataDocuments
ProgramFilesX86
AppDataFavorites
Searches
Local Downloads
SearchTemplatesFolder
Common Startup
ControlPanelFolder
SendTo
ResourceDir
ProgramFiles
CredentialManager
PrintHood
MAPIFolder
HomeGroupCurrentUserFolder
User Pinned
CD Burning
Local Music
UsersLibrariesFolder
AppUpdatesFolder
Application Shortcuts
Common Start Menu
Common Start Menu Places
LocalAppDataLow
OneDrive
Templates
Programs
PicturesLibrary
Roamed Tile Images
Camera Roll
Recent
AppDataDesktop
Desktop
CommonPictures
RecycleBinFolder
Screenshots
CryptoKeys
Common Templates
Startup
ImplicitAppShortcuts
UserProgramFilesCommon
Links
OEM Links
OneDriveMusic
Common Desktop
NetHood
Ringtones
Common Administrative Tools
NetworkPlacesFolder
SystemX86
History
Development Files
AddNewProgramsFolder
Playlists
ProgramFilesCommonX86
PublicGameTasks
ChangeRemoveProgramsFolder
Public
SavedPicturesLibrary
CommonRingtones
Common Documents
Captures
CSCFolder
Local AppData
Windows
UsersFilesFolder
Local Documents
ProgramFilesCommon
Fonts
Personal
```